# Exception Handling on sending a message via Kafka Template

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I was wondering if there is a way to catch an exception/throwable when producing a kafka message via the Kafka Template.

I don't see anything where it would throw a KafkaException if something fails. I need to find out if the message was committed to Kafka before I can continue with my application flow. I know the ListenableFuture would  log a failure but I don't know how to capture that onFailure.

```
public void sendToKafkaTopic(KafkaMessage data) {

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, KafkaMessage>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(primaryKafkaTopic, data);
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, KafkaMessage>>() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, KafkaMessage> result) {
        log.info("sent message='{}' with offset={}", data,
            result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        log.error("unable to send message='{}'", data, ex);
      }
    });
  }
```

I was trying to find something like this:

```
  public void sendToKafkaTopic(KafkaMessage data) {

    try {
      kafkaTemplate.send(primaryKafkaTopic, data);
    } catch (RuntimeException err) {
      log.error("unable to send message='{}'", data, ex);
      throw new CustomException(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> before I can continue with my application flow

There is nothing wrong if you just do `Future.get()`. When an exception happens downstream, it is going to be thrown to you from this blocking `get()`.

Comment: It's best to use the variant with a timeout (`get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`), just in case :)